# ¿Cómo filtrar un registro en una tabla oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, tablas

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
    Cuenta  Fecha   Estatus
      4315  01/05/20    1
      4315  01/05/20    2
      4315  01/05/20    3
      4410  02/05/20    1
      4410  03/05/20    2
      4410  03/05/20    3
```

Lo que necesito es mostrar el estatus 1 siempre y cuando el estatus 2 y 3 sean del mismo día. De lo contrario no mostrar nada, es decir, solo tendría que mostrar:

```
  Cuenta    Fecha   Estatus
    4315    01/05/20    1
```

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que hayas intentado al momento

Comment: Buenas. ¿Cual es la Primary Key de tu tabla?

Comment: y  que ha intentado?